# Laravel undefined function openssl_encrypt() in Encrypter.php

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, xampp

While fresh installing Laravel with Uniform Server, it shows error like

```
FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt()
in Encrypter.php (line 78)
```

I also did remove semicolon from `extension=php_openssl.dll`

Also in `phpinfo()`, it shows `OpenSSL Support: enabled`

Comment: Did you restart the apache?

Comment: yeah i did restrart